# SSRS - separate multiple values for a count

Tags: reporting-services, count

I have a field in my SSRS database that usually has one value assigned to it, but occasionally may have multiple values. Is it possible to separate these out so they can be individually counted? For example:

Ham; Count: 4

Turkey; Count: 2

Ham, Turkey; Count: 1

Should be:

Ham; Count: 5

Turkey; Count: 3

Comment: whats the logic behind this? why is Ham 5 and Turkey not 3 but keeps the original count of 2 in the desired result?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I've edited

Comment: Can we assume this is SQL Server? Also, is the data stored exactly as in your example in the form  **Item; Item; Item: Count n** ?

Comment: Yes, it is a SQL server. The data is not sorted as above, just written that way for presentation here. It is more like (without numbers below):

1. Ham
2. Ham
    Turkey
3. Turkey